# Uploading files to OneDrive programmatically: is there a way to avoid explicitly using username/password?

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

My task is to upload files to OneDrive programmatically using Python3. I found [**this recipe**](https://dev.to/jsnmtr/automating-files-upload-to-microsoft-onedrive-unexpected-challenges-and-a-success-story-2ini) with sample code that uses the [**MSAL library**](https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but the script requires including my username and password without any sort of encryption. I am OK with the username but not with the password. Is there a way around this? TIA!

Comment: 1) Why are you assuming no encryption? Incorrect assumption. 2) There are many ways to authenticate, user OAuth is just one method. 3) Are you an Azure AD Admin or have access to an Admin to create credentials for you? 4) The future is the Microsoft Graph API. I would start with Graph. Contrary to your article, I find Graph very easy to work with. 5) You do not even need to use a library, Python can make HTTP REST API calls that are very simple to code.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am following his instructions. Under "This is the main script, it creates a public client application..." the code sample shows that I need to include my password explicitly in the script that uploads files. This is what I am trying to avoid. Can you point me to any code samples that show, like the one above, all steps from establishing connection and authenticating to uploading a file, or performing a similar operation? Thx

Comment: @JohnHanley and to answer 3), no I am not an admin. I can get our admin to help set things up initially, but I can't reach out to them every time I need to run my scrip to upload something.

Comment: Microsoft offers many ways to authenticate and authorize. I would start at this beginning and just learn each one. Then you can decide which method fits your requirements. Regarding examples, there are dozens published by Microsoft and many on the Internet. However, relying on someone's example is like learning to walk by getting a ride in a car. Read the documentation and write your own code. You will have a much deeper understanding.